# How to stop ConcurrentModificationException when checking values of JSONobject

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am reading data in from a database, and then putting the data into a JSON object, which also contains an inner json object. Some of the data from the database comes back as "", and I want to remove the key and value for the object.

This is how the data comes:

```
 { 
  "foo": "bar",
   "bar": "",
   "foo": {
         "bar": "foo",
    },
    "bar": "foo"
    },
```

I want the data to look like this instead:

```
 { 
  "foo": "bar",
   "foo": {
         "bar": "foo",
    },
    "bar": "foo"
    },
```

I have tried using the below code

```
  private JSONObject removeEmpty(JSONObject root) {
    root.keys().forEachRemaining(key -> {
        Object value = root.get(key);
        if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            removeEmpty((JSONObject) value);
        } else if(value.equals("")) {
            root.remove(key);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

but I am getting a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error being thrown, and I'm unsure on how to resolve this within a json object. Does anyone have any suggestions in resolving this?

The stack track is

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1442)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1466)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at database.ConvertToJSON.removeEmpty(ConvertToJSON.java:48)
at database.ConvertToJSON.convertToJSON(ConvertToJSON.java:40)
at database.Database.searchByLocation(Database.java:24)
at Application$1.handle(Application.java:30)
at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:72)
at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
at spark.embeddedserver.jetty.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:50)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
at com.spark.shaded.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Use an iterator instead of `forEachRemaining`.

Comment: The error printout would help if you could provide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove items from an object while iterating over it as you are doing in your `forEachRemaining`. You either can mark the items you want to remove (as below) or create a copy to iterate over and remove from the original object.

```
private JSONObject removeEmpty(JSONObject root) {
    ArrayList<Object> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
    root.keys().forEachRemaining(key -> {
        Object value = root.get(key);
        if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            removeEmpty((JSONObject) value);
        } else if(value.equals("")) {
            toRemove.add(key)
        }
    });

    foreach (Object o : toRemove) {
        root.remove((String)o);
    }

    return root;
}
```

If you get the same error but with regards to the value, you'll need to do the same thing but for the values.

Comment: Hi, just tried that then, but im getting an issue with the remove types, not if if i've missed anything. Thank you btw 
`(java.lang.String)
in JSONObject cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.Object)`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I forgot to cast it to a string. Updated the answer

Comment: In Java a foreach loop still uses the `for` keyword.

To be clear, this answer solves the problem, because you can't remove items from an object while iterating over it. You either can mark the items you want to remove (like in the answer) or create a copy to iterate over and remove from the original object.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda hi, this works really well thank you!

Comment: @BreakBB hi, thank you for your explanation,I understand the issue fully now, thank you again everybody

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark the answer as the solution so others can find it easily.